# Coedit mode on Emacs

Tags: package, package-development

I often use the web service Kobra.io, in which we can edit a specific file with some people together at the same time.

Is there such a package on Emacs?

I'd like to edit a specific lisp code at the same time with some people.

If I change some parts in the code, the other people can see the change at the same time.

Could you tell me how to implement this function?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/66730 -- I suspect one of these should be closed as a duplicate of the other.  (I would favour the other Q&A over this, because one of the answers links to the Emacs Wiki page which lists many solutions.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do live sharing for pair programming in emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66730/how-to-do-live-sharing-for-pair-programming-in-emacs)

Answer (score 1):

There's `rudel`, available on GNU ELPA, which intends to do that (it supports various protocols of communication between the various Emacs sessions).

Comment: I used package-install to install the package, but it doesn't work on my Macbook's Emacs 25.093.

When I start the rudel, the error happend as follows:
slot-value: eieio-oref called on a class: rudel-backend-factory

Comment: I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` and we'll take it from there.

Comment: This was probably [Bug#23996](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23996), which has been fixed by now.

Answer (score 1):

There is [floobits](https://github.com/Floobits/floobits-emacs). It works OK.

Answer (score 0):

A pure Lisp alternative called shared-buffer was developed during the Lisp in Summer projects 7 years ago.  It requires a Common Lisp server (also distributed as part of the repo).

- https://github.com/larstvei/shared-buffer-lisp-in-summer-projects

In principle it may be possible to port the Common Lisp portion to Emacs Lisp, for a 100% Emacs based solution, but at the time of writing that has not been done.