# How to do live sharing for pair programming in emacs?

Tags: untagged

I want to do live sharing in emacs as vscode does.

Anybody know how can I do that?

Comment: Can you describe what VScode does? It might help clarify what exactly you are asking. Remember that this is an *Emacs* forum, so even though some people might know a little (or a lot) about VScode, you should  assume that people here know *nothing* about VScode and frame your question accordingly.

Comment: I want to have like this https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/collaboration/live-share , in my emacs. Thank you for helping

Comment: You could try https://floobits.com/help/plugins/emacs. I don’t know how well it works, and it might not be free.

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/28915 -- I suspect one of these should be closed as a duplicate of the other. (I would favour the present Q&A over the linked one, on account of the answer linking to the Emacs Wiki page, which lists many solutions.)

Answer (score 2):

There's really no good solution yet but `crdt` is reportedly getting close. Check out [the Emacs Wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CollaborativeEditing).

Comment: Fascinating, I wish I could use it with my colleagues. The world has moved so much from building interopable protocols to walled gardens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still a workable solution in 2021, but years ago I shared my Emacs session with a non-Emacs collaborator via [floobits](https://github.com/Floobits/floobits-emacs) and it was pretty great.