# setting up a remote emacs pairing session without access to the filesystem

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs

I'm just wondering if it's possible to setup an emacs pairing session over ssh where in one session, I have access to the filesystem but the other person I'm pairing with doesn't?

Comment: Does this help? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/66730

Comment: Or this? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/28915

Comment: At a glance, https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/crdt.html looks like the most actively maintained approach, so I would look at that first.  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CollaborativeEditing lists various other approaches.  I think this can probably be closed as a duplicate of one of those other questions, pending confirmation that one of those solutions is successful.

Comment: I think so. Because the collaborator and I are in different locations, I was hoping to log both of us in to a common server. I was thinking of sharing across different linux accounts on the same server but the crdt would work fine. Thanks!